# Use Powershell to convert a text file into a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

If I have a simple text file showing user's first name, middle name (if available), last name, and email address, is there a quick way to convert this to a csv format using Powershell or maybe even Excel? The CSV file would only need to show the first name, last name (which could be a combination of middle name and last name), and email address.

For example, if I have a text file as follows:

```
James Tiberius Kirk       james.kirk@starfleet.com
Leonard McCoy             leonard.mccoy@starfleet.com
```

I would like to convert to csv as follows:

```
FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress
James,TiberiusKirk,james.kirk@starfleet.com
Leonard,McCoy,leonard.mccoy@starfleet.com
```

Am not sure how to do, other than manually, which is time consuming for large text files.

Comment: Is there more than one person in each file.  One example is not enough because there may be blank lines and other characters in the file that are needed to parse all the people in the file.

Answer (score 5):

Preface:

- The most robust way to parse such data would be to either *know the fixed width of columns* in the plain-text file or to have an *unambiguous separator* between columns.
- In your case, it *may* be the case that *two or more spaces* constitute such a separator, but that cannot be inferred from your sample data.
- However, the fact that the *last* column value - the email address - never contains spaces and that there are only *two* columns allows unambiguous parsing: the last whitespace-separated token is the email address, everything before that is the name.

---

Let me complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887494/45375) with a solution that uses a rarely seen [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) feature (which, if memory serves, Mathias himself even implemented):

- The ability of the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator to accept a *negative* number to limit the number of tokens to return, which causes the splitting to occur from the *end* of each input string.

```bash
# PS 7+ only
Get-Content file.txt | 
  ForEach-Object {
    # Split by one or more spaces into two tokens *from the end* (-2)
    # E.g., 'James Tiberius Kirk       james.kirk@starfleet.com' becomes
    #       @('James Tiberius Kirk', 'james.kirk@starfleet.com')
    $name, $email = $_ -split ' +', -2
    $first, $middleLast = -split $name
    [pscustomobject] @{
      FirstName    = $first
      LastName     = -join $middleLast
      EmailAddress = $email
    }
  } |
  ConvertTo-Csv # output to screen; replace with Export-Csv to save to file.
```

Comment: I should keep better track of my own features :-P

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-split` operator to split the name and email addresses apart, then use it again for the name components, and finally pipe your results to `Export-Csv`:

```
Get-Content contacts.txt |ForEach-Object {
  # trim whitespace from input, separate name and email
  $name,$email = $_.Trim() -split '\s{2,}',2

  # split first name and rest from name
  $fn,$ln = $name -split '\s',2

  # create output object
  [pscustomobject]@{
    FirstName = $fn
    LastName = $ln
    EmailAddress = $email
  }
} |Export-Csv path\to\destination.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Nice however splitting by the `\s{2,}` regex fails if there is only one space between name and email…

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like that. Just change "inputpath" and "outputpath" and save the script here as a .ps1

```
$textFilePath = "inputpath\docToConvert.txt"

$csvFilePath = "outputpath/convertedDoc.csv"

$lines = Get-Content $textFilePath

$csvData = @()

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $parts = -split $line

    $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        FirstName = $parts[0]
        LastName = ($parts[1..($parts.Length - 2)] -join "")
        EmailAddress = $parts[-1]
    }

    $csvData += $object
}

$csvData | Export-Csv $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: +1, but note that "extending" arrays in a loop with `+=` is inefficient, because a _new_ array must be created behind the scenes _in every iteration_, given that arrays are of fixed size; a much more efficient approach is to use a `foreach` loop as an _expression_ and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `$csvData = foreach (...) { ... }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375) for background.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it. It is not clear why the LastName field would have multiple parts with no space, but this does it. The LastName is produce by a slice of the $All array.

```
#Requires -Version 7
Get-Content -Path '.\na.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $All = $_ -split '\s+'
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FirstName = $All[0]
        LastName = ($All.Count -ge 3) ? ($All[1..($All.Count - 2)] -join '') : $null
        EmailAddress = $All[-1]
    }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -UseQuotes AsNeeded
```

This uses some features in PowerShell Core. If you are still on Windows PowerShell, then a) upgrade or b) make changes to the script.

```
PS C:\src> Get-Content -Path .\na.txt
James Tiberius Kirk       james.kirk@starfleet.com
Leonard McCoy             leonard.mccoy@starfleet.com
prince                    prince@nowhere.com

PS C:\src> .\na.ps1
FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress
James,TiberiusKirk,james.kirk@starfleet.com
Leonard,McCoy,leonard.mccoy@starfleet.com
prince,,prince@nowhere.com

PS C:\src> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.8
```